# Continuous Different Errors

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have edited the SQL to use DISTINCT however I am still getting the same data as when I use GROUP BY. Any suggestions? 
When I use GROUP BY it requires that all the fields in the select clause are included, can anyone tell me why that is?

## Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
TrnClaim.ClientID
, TrnClaim.FileNo
, TrnLegend.RecordNo
, RTRIM(dbo.TrnClient.ClientName + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.TrnClient.Initials,'') + ' ' +     (CASE WHEN dbo.TrnClient.LanguageCode = 'A' THEN ISNULL(dbo.TrnClient.Title, 'Mr') ELSE ISNULL(dbo.TrnClient.Title,'')END)) AS NameInitials
, TrnClient.IDNumber
, ISNULL(dbo.MstInsurer.InsurerName, 'Unknown') AS InsurerName
, CAST(dbo.TrnPolicy.AgentID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(CAST(dbo.MstAgent.AgentName AS VARCHAR(50)),'Unknown') AS AgentIDName
, CAST(dbo.TrnPolicy.TeamID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.VieTeamSelect.TeamName, 'Unknown') AS TeamIDName
, CAST(dbo.TrnPolicy.LinkID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstLink.LinkName, 'Unknown') AS LinkIDName
, CAST(dbo.TrnPolicy.SubagentID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstSubagent.SubagentName, 'Unknown') AS SubagentIDName
, CAST(dbo.TrnPolicy.MarketerID AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' ' + ISNULL(dbo.MstMarketerCodes.MarketerName, 'Unknown') AS MarketerIDName
, dbo.TrnRisk.RiskID
, dbo.TrnRisk.Registration
, dbo.TrnRisk.VehID
, dbo.TrnRisk.VinNo
, dbo.TrnRisk.VehMake
, dbo.TrnRisk.VehMake
, dbo.TrnRisk.VehModel
, dbo.TrnRisk.VehModel
, dbo.TrnExt.ExtStartDate
, dbo.TrnExt.ExtEndDate
, dbo.MstRateCodes.RateCodeID
, dbo.TrnExt.ExtDesc
, dbo.TrnPolicy.Status AS PolicyStatus
, dbo.TrnPolicy.PayMeth
, dbo.TrnPolicy.PolicyPeriod
, 1 AS [Count]
, dbo.TrnPolicy.TotalPrem AS LastMonthPremium
--, LastPolicy.TotalDue AS LastMonthTotalDue
, dbo.TrnPolicy.TeamID
, dbo.TrnPolicy.AgentID
, dbo.TrnPolicy.LinkID
, ISNULL(dbo.TrnPolicy.LeadInsurerID,MstInsurer.InsurerID) AS InsurerIDForFilter
, dbo.TrnLegend.LegendDescr
, dbo.TrnLegend.ActiveDate

FROM dbo.TrnClaim

INNER JOIN dbo.TrnPolicy ON
    TrnClaim.ClientID = dbo.TrnPolicy.ClientID 
    AND
    TrnClaim.FileNo = dbo.TrnPolicy.FileNo 

INNER JOIN dbo.TrnClient ON 
    dbo.TrnPolicy.ClientID = dbo.TrnClient.ClientID 

INNER JOIN dbo.TrnRisk ON 
    dbo.TrnPolicy.ClientID = dbo.TrnRisk.ClientID 
    AND 
    dbo.TrnPolicy.FileNo = dbo.TrnRisk.FileNo 

INNER JOIN dbo.TrnExt ON 
    dbo.TrnRisk.ClientID = dbo.TrnExt.ClientID 
    AND 
    dbo.TrnRisk.FileNo = dbo.TrnExt.FileNo 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstRateCodes ON 
    dbo.MstRateCodes.RateCodeID = dbo.TrnExt.ExtCode    

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstInsurer MstInsurerLead ON 
    dbo.TrnPolicy.LeadInsurerID = MstInsurerLead.InsurerID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TrnPolicy LastPolicy ON  
    dbo.TrnPolicy.ClientID = LastPolicy.ClientID 
    AND 
    dbo.TrnPolicy.FileNo = LastPolicy.FileNo 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstAgent ON 
    dbo.TrnPolicy.AgentID = dbo.MstAgent.AgentID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstSubagent ON 
    dbo.TrnPolicy.SubagentID = dbo.MstSubagent.SubagentID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstMarketerCodes ON 
    dbo.TrnPolicy.MarketerID = dbo.MstMarketerCodes.MarketerID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.VieTeamSelect ON
    dbo.TrnPolicy.TeamID = dbo.VieTeamSelect.TeamID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstLink ON  
    dbo.TrnPolicy.LinkID = dbo.MstLink.LinkID 

LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MstInsurer ON 
    dbo.MstInsurer.InsurerID= dbo.TrnClaim.InsurerID

INNER JOIN dbo.TrnLegend On
    dbo.TrnLegend.ClientID = dbo.TrnClaim.ClientID
    AND
    dbo.TrnLegend.FileNo = dbo.TrnClaim.FileNo


WHERE 
Upper(dbo.TrnLegend.LegendDescr) LIKE '%CANCELLED%'

Order By 
dbo.TrnClaim.ClientID
, dbo.TrnClaim.FileNo
, dbo.TrnLegendRecordNo
```

Comment: Paste in the exact error so we know which columns it is complaining about

Comment: Ummm... you've dumped a large SQL statement and said you get "errors". You haven't posted what you're trying to achieve or what those errors are. How can anyone possibly help? Break it down. Delete most of your statement and try to build it up. You will be more likely to find what's the problem than having random people on the internet guess for you.

Comment: `if all 3 of the WHERE clauses are active it runs but returns no data` OK! Interesting! But what did you expect for results?

Comment: Why are you grouping?  I may be missing it but I don't see why you need to.

Comment: If you want distinct records you may use `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`

Comment: I can see no reason why you need the grouping. As already advised use distinct if you do not want duplicate records. Remove the grouping and keep the where.  Which field if 'Absa Insurance and Financial Advisers (Pty) Limited' coming from?

Comment: The problem is I don't actually know. I am new and there is far to much data for me to keep track of.

Comment: Hi Michael, for us to help you, you will have to give us the error you receive when you execute this statement. If not, this query looks fine.

Comment: Yes however it is returning more data than is required. I am going to try removing some fields.

Comment: Well got it working thanks for the suggestions, sorry the question was badly asked.

Comment: Well at least you got where you needed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Group By` you specify list of attributes. A query that contains a `GROUP BY` clause generates **one row per group based on each unique combination of values of the attributes that belong to the grouping set**.

Consequently, when `GROUP BY` is specified in a query, all subsequent steps (HAVING, SELECT, and so on) can specify only expressions that have a scalar (singular) value per group. These expressions can include columns or expressions from the GROUP BY list like TrnClaim.ClientID —or aggregate functions, such as COUNT(TrnClaim.ClientID).

As I can see you have not included any aggregate function in your query above that's why when you write say Group By (TrnClaim.ClientID) or any other column then no group is created or to rephrase each row becomes a unique group and so it requires that all the fields in the select clause are included.

That's the reason why you are getting same data with Distinct and GROUP BY becuase no group has been created.